# PHP - $_POST['variable'] echos correctly but returns false in if statement

Tags: php, post, if-statement

I have a htm file that passes a variable called $team to a php file.  The php file echo's 'Fred' just fine on line 3 if that is what the user inputs but an if statement which asks `if $_POST["team"] == "Fred"` always returns negative.  Can anyone help?

```
<?php

        echo $_POST["team"] , "<br />";

        if ($_POST["team"] ==  "Fred"){
            echo "You go for " , $_POST["team"];
        }

        else {
            echo "You do NOT go for Fred";
        }

?>
```

Output:

Fred

You do NOT go for Fred

Comment: I don't know if this is the case, but have you tried to use trim() in the $_POST["team"] ? try to store the value into a variable eg: $var = trim($_POST["team"]); and then, compare with your string if($var == "Fred");

Comment: Ah, there's another thing in your echo inside the if condition: You can't use comma to concatenate strings. You must use dot (.) to do that. 
echo "You go for " , $_POST["team"];

Comment: Thank you Thiago, I made both of the changes you suggested and it worked perfectly.  Seems as though the trim method made all the difference.  I will find out how to mark as answered and give your response a +vote.

Comment: My mistake with commas. Sorry, you may use it in echo.

Comment: I'm glad it works =D! I posted an answer explaining why trim works. If you can upvote it or accept it, It will be awesome =D

Comment: I have accepted but can't upvote because I am a noob.  Thank Thiago.  Super impressed with accuracy and speed of all of the responses.

Comment: haha, actually, you accepted the other answer, but no problem, man. haha Sometimes I`m impressed how fast stackoverflow is fast when you're in trouble.. =D

Comment: Sorry Thiago, I definately credit you with getting me on the right track but FAQ says accept the answer that is correct and most efficient so that was the other one unfortunately.  If I get 5 more reputations I will be able to vote answers up and I will give you some credit that way.

Comment: No Problem Mark! The important is that your problem was solved ! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $_POST["team"] has spaces. Try this:

```
<?php

    echo $_POST["team"] , "<br />";

    if (trim($_POST["team"]) ==  "Fred"){
        echo "You go for " , $_POST["team"];
    }

    else {
        echo "You do NOT go for Fred";
    }
```

?>

Note: this code is not related to the (,) Because you using echo, not merge string

Answer (score 0):

If your `$_POST['team']` contains spaces, the comparison will always return `false`.

Try to use `trim()` [(Documentation here)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). Trim remove all spaces in your string, so it will reduce chances to fall in errors like these.

```
<?php

    $team = trim($_POST['team']);

    echo $team , "<br />";

    if ($team ==  "Fred"){
        echo "You go for " , $_POST["team"];
    }

    else {
        echo "You do NOT go for Fred";
    }

?>
```

Let me know if it works =D

Answer (score -2):

you can `echo` like this because `merge` string in php use .

```
if ($_POST["team"] ==  "Fred"){
    echo "You go for " . $_POST["team"];
}
```